# lazy evaluation

Tags: haskell

I am not good to speak english.

I think. It will be evaluated, and print "abc", "efg".

```
main =  return (map putStrLn ["abc", "efg"]) >> return ()
```

but, I tested it, and it does not work.

Comment: Appending spam to the question is *not* a good response to "your question is too short"! A better way might be adding more useful information ;) For instance, explain why you believe it should print something.

Answer (score 7):

```
map putStrLn ["abc", "efg"]
```

returns a list of values of type `[IO ()]`, which you are then not executing; instead, you are calling `return` on the list to get a value of type `IO [IO ()]`.

You can execute a list of `IO a` values with the `sequence_` function:

```
main  =  sequence_ (map putStrLn ["abc", "efg"])
```

Or use the shorthand `mapM_`:

```
main  =  mapM_ putStrLn ["abc", "efg"]
```

Answer (score 5):

In any monad, `return x >> y` is the same as `y` due to the [monad laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws).

```
return x >> y
= return x >>= \_ -> y    -- definition of >>
= (\_ -> y) x             -- left identity monad law
= y                       -- apply the lambda
```

Thus, `return (map putStrLn ["abc", "efg"]) >> return ()` is the same as `return ()` which is why nothing happens. Lazy evaluation has nothing to do with it.

The easiest fix is to use `mapM_`, as shown in the other answer.